# Configuring the time lag between inserting/deleting a row in a table and updating the systabstats.rowcnt value in Sybase

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase, rowcount

I found that there is a time lag of close to a minute between inserting/deleting a row in a table in sybase and updating the systabstats.rowcnt value for that table. I need to get the current row count at a certain moment and I can't fire "update statistics" or anything else before fetching the row count. 
Is there any way of reducing/configuring the time lag and not use count(*)
The query I am using is

> `SELECT sysobjects.name, systabstats.rowcnt, sysusers.name as username, systabstats.statmoddate FROM sysobjects JOIN systabstats ON (sysobjects.id = systabstats.id) join sysusers on (sysobjects.uid = sysusers.uid)`

Comment: I don't think this relates to sybase-asa in any way, I suggest you remove that tag to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Housekeeper (or HK WASH) process is what writes the dirty pages and updates `systabstats`.  You can play around with the server settings for those processes to get the updates to run more frequently.

Alternatively you can force the system to flush the statistics from cache to `systabstats` using [sp_flushstats](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00976.1570/html/statistics/X13102.htm)

```
sp_flushstats [TABLENAME]
```

If you do not specify a table, it will flush statistics for all tables in the current database.